# Execution failed for task: react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run "react-native run-android" after installing "react-native-camera-tflite" package, and keep getting the error "Task :react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac"

```
> Task :react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
42 actionable tasks: 35 executed, 7 up-to-date
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-camera\android\src\main\java\com\google\android\cameraview\Camera2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-camera-tflite\android\src\main\java\com\google\android\cameraview\Camera2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java:435: error: cannot find symbol
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable P
  location: class VERSION_CODES
D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java:437: error: cannot find symbol
        locationEnabled = mLocationManager.isLocationEnabled();
                                          ^
  symbol:   method isLocationEnabled()
  location: variable mLocationManager of type LocationManager
Note: D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-camera\android\src\main\java\com\google\android\cameraview\Camera2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-camera-tflite\android\src\main\java\com\google\android\cameraview\Camera2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java:435: error: cannot find symbol
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable P
  location: class VERSION_CODES
D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java:437: error: cannot find symbol
        locationEnabled = mLocationManager.isLocationEnabled();
                                          ^
  symbol:   method isLocationEnabled()
  location: variable mLocationManager of type LocationManager
Note: D:\react native\loro\node_modules\react-native-device-info\android\src\main\java\com\learnium\RNDeviceInfo\RNDeviceModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 6s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\react native\loro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\react native\loro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:169:41)
    at then.result (D:\react native\loro\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/434 and i think it was solved with this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info/issues/365#issuecomment-425609406